# Breeze.js 1.4.1 properties undefined not null

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze

I upgraded to 1.4.1 per the recommendation of Breeze support but I am having the following issue. Previously, the navigation properties on newly created entities where defined, but null valued knockout observables. I modified the Breezejs TODO application to show this.

My data model is below, and my front end code is here:

```
function reproduce() {
  breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
  var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
  manager.fetchMetadata().then(function () {
    var parent = manager.createEntity('Parent');
    console.log('otherProperty ' + parent.otherProperty());
    console.log('childOne ' + parent.childOne());
    // I cannot call parent.childrenTwo() since childrenTwois undefined
    console.log('childrenTwo ' + parent.childrenTwo);
  });
}
```

The issue is that in previous versions of breeze, the properties otherProperty and childOne would be a knockout observable with a null value and the property childrenTwo would be an empty observable array. *However, as I see in the console all three properties are undefined? Is this intentional?*

I could of course define them myself but that is a lot of work and something I expect breeze todo for me. Also according to the Breeze docs "There is rarely reason to define properties that are already described in metadata." http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities

**Update 1:**

Thanks to Jay Traband, in my reproduction app I was not setting casing correctly. However childrenTwo is still undefined and I believe it should be an observable array. My production app does set casing so I'll have to re-investigate that.

**Update 2:**

Thanks again to Jay Traband, I found that the breeze metastore does not know about the ChildTwo type. Therefore it seems I am not registering it somehow? I am much more familiar with Java Hibernate than Entity Framework. Is something missing from my data model below?

**Updated 3:**

ChildTwo didn't have an explicit foreign key, I added that and it worked. I guess I really need to take to heart that Breeze wants an explicit foreign key.

```
public class ChildTwo
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public int ParentId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
  public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Data model.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
namespace Todo.Models
{
  public class Parent
  {
    public Parent()
    {
      ChildrenTwo = new List<ChildTwo>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ChildOne ChildOne { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public IList<ChildTwo> ChildrenTwo { get; set; }
  }
  public class ChildOne
  {
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
  }
  public class ChildTwo
  {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is probably a copy paste error, but you realize that if those properties are observables that you need to use parans correct?  ie - console.log('otherProperty ' + parent().otherProperty()); if you want to get the property, parent().otherProperty if you want to see if it is not undefined?

Comment: Since those properties are undefined, calling them like a function results in an error. The log calls are just to show me if they are undefined or actually observable. I added a comment describing why I cannot () call the properties.

Comment: Calling them with parent().otherProperty should not return an error...  Also consider marking answers in your previously asked questions as accepted to help others find them in the future.

Comment: parent().otherProperty does not work. Error is as expected "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function". I marked my other questions answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did some simple tests and was unable to repro this. I see navigation properties for my entities as knockout observables in all of my tests after calling *createEntity*. A couple of ideas;

Are you sure that you aren't inadvertantly

- using the **backingStore** or **backbone** model library instead of **knockout**. via *breeze.config.initializeAdapter*.
- applying a different casing to your properties, i.e. via use of *breeze.NamingConvention*.

Comment: The casing property in my reproduction app was incorrect. The properties otherProperty and childOne now are defined correctly. However, childrenTwo is still undefined and based on my model I feel like it should be an empty observable array?

Comment: Use the MetadataStore.getEntityType method to see what Breeze thinks the metadata properties for your "Parent" type.  My guess is that you won't see a "ChildTwo" navigation property.  If so, then it is likely that you haven't configured your server side properly for Entity Framework, because this metadata is being retrieved from the EF DbContext.

Comment: You are correct sir! getPropertyNames() does not return ChildrenTwo. Sorry, I am new to .NET (java guy), I added a DBSet of ChildTwo to the DBContext but it still doesn't show up? Am I missing some of kind of annotation above?

Comment: I updated the post but the issue was no explicit foreign key. Future readers, make sure you have explicit foreign keys!

Comment: Glad you found it and thanks for updating your post.  BTW, we will be releasing NHibernate support for Breeze soon in case you are more comfortable with that. Although honestly once you get used to EF you may actually prefer it.